# How does one run and debug a WAR with Spring STS?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, pivotal-web-services

I'm new to Spring, but over the past month have built a nice Spring Boot app using STS 3.7 and the latest Spring Boot.

Now, I have an older Spring project (I think it goes back to Spring 2.0, but it may be 2.5) and I am trying to work on it using STS 3.7. I imported it from the pom.xml and fixed a few small config errors here and there, and now I'm trying to make it run. It is in production on Java 1.6 and I am trying to get it working on 1.8 with Spring 4, but most important I need to add an enhancement to it.

When I try to run it using Pivotal TC, Pivotal starts and I can get the Pivotal page at http://localhost:8080 but when I try to access my application I get a 404 page saying "the requested resource is not available."

When I start Pivotal, here is what I see on the console:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Jul 31, 2015 6:53:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 580 ms
Jul 31, 2015 6:53:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 349 ms
```

There is no mention of my app being loaded or deployed, but I don't know if that's normal.

I put some breakpoints in, but they are never hit. So I have no idea if my application is being loaded into the server, or if the server is starting but there is some error loading my application. The error page does, however, have my favicon on the tab.

I can build my WAR from the command line if I do this:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

So I don't know where to go from here. How do I figure out what is happening? I can't find any logs and I have poked all through the STS settings. I'm not even sure STS is building the Java code successfully, since there is no output to a console during the build process (I have tried both with automatic build and manual build).

Thanks very much...